# Why doesn't ListPointPlot3D plot a Table's output that iterates over three variables?

Tags: plotting

Why does `ListPointPlot3D` accept tables with 3 outputs and 2 variables such as:

```
Table[{a,b,1},{a,-1,1},{b,-1,1}]
ListPointPlot3D[Table[{a,b,1},{a,-1,1},{b,-1,1}]]
```

but doesn't accept tables with 3 outputs and 3 variables?

```
Table[{a,b,c},{a,-1,1},{b,-1,1},{c,-1,1}]
ListPointPlot3D[Table[{a,b,c},{a,-1,1},{b,-1,1},{c,-1,1}]]
```

Am I doing something wrong or is Mathematica stupid?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: Try: `t2 = Flatten[Table[{a, b, c}, {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {c, -1, 1}], 2]` and `ListPointPlot3D[t2]` OR `t3 = Flatten[Table[{a, b, c}, {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {c, -1, 1}], 1]` and `ListPointPlot3D[t3]`.

Comment: Ah that works altho I dont understand why. Thanks

Comment: Run `Dimensions` on the outputs of your `Table` expressions to see the structure of the lists being generated, and compare those with the allowable inputs for `ListPointPlot3D` mentioned in the documentation. As an alternative to your second example, consider `Tuples[Range[-1, 1], 3]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

To see why the approaches given in  Syed's comment work, compare the [`Dimensions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dimensions.html) of the [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)s

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Dimensions[t1 = Table[{a, b, 1}, {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}]]

(* {3, 3, 3} *)
```

There are three lists of three data points

```
ListPointPlot3D[t1, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
Dimensions[t2 = Table[{a, b, c}, {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {c, -1, 1}]]

(* {3, 3, 3, 3} *)
```

This dataset does not match any allowed syntax for ListPointPlot3D

```
ListPointPlot3D[t2]

(* ListPointPlot3D::ldata: {{{{-1,-1,-1},{-1,-1,0},{-1,-1,1}},{{-1,0,-1},{-1,0,0},{-1,0,1}},{{-1,1,-1},{-1,1,0},{-1,1,1}}},{<<1>>},{<<1>>}} is not a valid dataset or list of datasets. *)

Dimensions[
 t3 = Flatten[Table[{a, b, c}, {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {c, -1, 1}], 2]]

(* {27, 3} *)
```

This is a single list of 27 data points

```
ListPointPlot3D[t3, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
Dimensions[
 t4 = Flatten[Table[{a, b, c}, {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {c, -1, 1}], 1]]

(* {9, 3, 3} *)
```

This is nine lists of three data points

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Flatten[Table[{a, b, c}, {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {c, -1, 1}], 1], 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]